# Error Intel XDK Register

Tags: intel-xdk

This happens when I try to login or register me in Intel XDK.
what I do?

PS. I already have an account; disabled the firewall too.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YrbG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Intel XDK build is broken. Go here to download the previous version: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/705276

Search for xdk_web_win_master_3759